# Is there a way to automate restart of Azure App Service Environment(ASE) so that it can be included in the pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-app-service-envrmnt, azure-pipelines-yaml

As part of Failover/negative testing, want to restart Azure App Service Environment in pipeline. Currently it's being done manually using restart button of ASE resource in Azure Portal

As a part of research came across App Service Environment -Reboot API (Reboot all machines in an App Service Environment)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/appserviceenvironments/reboot
Wondering is this same as ASE restart from Azure portal?
or Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Hi, Did below answer what you were looking for. Could you [accept it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the API documented by https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/appserviceenvironments/reboot will effectively reboot the ASE. It will return a `202` and header called `Location`.  You can invoke this REST API from your Azure DevOps Pipeline a number of ways.  The method I prefer is to use the [Invoke-RestMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7.1) using Powershell so that you can use the response `Location` header to await the `200` response which means the reboot operation has concluded.